# Sonic Pi returning errors for crucial functions

Tags: software-development, sonic-pi

I have recently messed around with Sonic Pi and I have got it to play MIDI notes (via `play ??`.)

However, I am attempting to follow the guide to SonicPi in the [MagPi issue 23](http://www.themagpi.com/issue/issue-23/) and it told me to enter `sample :loop_amen` as my first command. I did so and pressed ran. However, I am getting this error:

```
/opt/sonic-pi/app/gui/../../app/scripts/run-code.rb:288: in `eval': undefined method `sample` for #<SpiderLang:0x160f950> (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/sonic-pi/app/gui/../../app/scripts/run-code.rb:288: in `eval'
    from /opt/sonic-pi/app/gui/../../app/scripts/run-code.rb:288: in `spider_eval'
    from /opt/sonic-pi/app/gui/../../app/scripts/run-code.rb:288: in `<main>'
```

So, I figured oh well. It's just a sample, it's not important. So I kept going and then they had me enter

```
with_fx :reverb do
    sample :guit_e_fifths
end
```

and I get the exact same error, except with a different `SpiderLang` address.

Does anyone have any clue why all of these errors are occurring? I really want to try out SonicPi, but I can't with these.

Comment: Are you sure you're running version 2 of Sonic Pi?

Comment: No, actually, I'm not. I'm running 1.0. I didn't realize that 2.0 wasn't available in the Repos yet. I mis-read that section of the article. :P Thanks for the pointer! If you could create an answer, that would be stupendous :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running version 2 of Sonic Pi for these new functions to work.

Version 2 is available from: http://sonic-pi.net/get-v2.0

Full instructions are on that page. I won't duplicate them here because the new version is still being developed and the release candidate number for the download is being updated regularly.

Comment: Cool. Version 2 is fantastic. Sam Aaron's really put a lot of work in.